# Doubled fields in Adminthml grid page of a Custom Extension

Tags: adminhtml

i'm working on a custom Magento(1.9.0.1) extension.

Let me show you my problem in pictures:

**When i click the button to go to the next page:**
[image]

**I got this problem:**

[image]

As you can see it is doubling by any reason the Magento fields pointed in the picture and the `Loading` block in the middle is not fading away.

Let me show you my entire config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource</resourceModel>
        </smsnotification>
        <vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
        <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <smsnotification>
            <table>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</table>
            </smsnotification>
            <smsnotificationhistory>
            <table>VivasIndustries_SmsHistory</table>
            </smsnotificationhistory>
        </entities>
        </vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <smsnotification_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                 <use>core_setup</use>
             </connection>
        </smsnotification_setup>
        <smsnotification_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_read>
        <smsnotification_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_write>
    </resources>    
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <vivasindustries_smsnotification>
                    <class>smsnotification/observer</class>
                    <method>orderSaved</method>
                </vivasindustries_smsnotification>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
    <helpers>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <smsnotification>
             <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <vivas>
                                        <title>Vivas - All</title>
                                    </vivas>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <smsnotification>
                <file>smsnotification.xml</file>
            </smsnotification>
        </updates>
    </layout>   
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification before="Mage_Adminhtml">VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml</VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Here is the files that is creating the grid table:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_History extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container


{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sms_history';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'smsnotification';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('SMS History');

        parent::__construct();

        $this->_removeButton('add');
    }
}
```

And:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_History_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('smsnotification_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }


    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('smsnotification/smsnotificationhistory_collection');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }


    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
          $this->addColumn('id', array(
              'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('ID'),
              'align'     =>'right',
              'width'     => '50px',
              'index'     => 'id',
          ));

          $this->addColumn('receiver', array(
              'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Receiver'),
              'align'     =>'left',
              'index'     => 'receiver',
          ));

        $this->addColumn('phone', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Phone'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'phone',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('email', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Email'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'email',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('smstext', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('SMS Text'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'smstext',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('date', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Date'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'date',
        ));



        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id'=>$row->getId()));
    }
}
```

I don't know where is my mistake and why it is doubling these fields.
Do you have any idea how to resolve this problem ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a gridAction in your controller.

So in your `*_Grid` block add

```
public function getGridUrl() {
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current' => true));
}
```

In you controller add

```
public function gridAction() {
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('{yourmodule}/adminhtml_*_grid')
            ->toHtml());
}
```